# Need help regarding NFS shares permissions

Tags: permissions, virtual-machines, nfs, proxmox, lxc

I recently switched to using `Proxmox` as my `OS` of choice from `OMV` as the main `OS` and running a bunch of `docker` containers on the same host. I installed `OMV` (`OpenMediaVault`) inside a `VM`. I passed through my already existing 4TB drive and everything is good so far. Now I learned that in `Proxmox` if I use `unprivilged LXC` container, I need to mount either `NFS` or `SMB` share to `Proxmox` and then `bind mount` that share via `CLI` to that `LXC`. And if I choose to use a `VM` then I can just straight mount the share inside `VM`. I choose to use `NFS` for both scenarios, however I am having some problems with permission. For example I created 1 `VM` for `Jellyfin` (media streaming software), in this `VM` I installed `Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS` and I created a user `apoorv` which has a `UID` of `1000`. Now the in host `OS` `Proxmox` I also created a user as I didn't wanted to use the `root` account all the time. So I created a user called `proxmox` which also has `UID` of `1000`. Now in the `OMV VM` I have 4 users, 3 for real people (family/friends) and 1 for managing the shares and all, I called the user `proxmox` which also has `UID` of `1000`. Now I have a share for `Jellyfin` called `media`, here is a screenshot for permissions of the `media` share

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GQEI.png)

and here is a screenshot for the `ACL` of `media` share,

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcBWS.png)
[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAZsj.png)

and here is a screenshot for the `NFS` share I created for `media`

[screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fSAQ.png)

I have tried with both with and without the `anonuid/anongid`.

Now in the `VM` I mounted this share under `/mnt/media`, for adding this I have this in my `/etc/fstab` file,

```
IP:/export/media      /mnt/media      nfs     rw,soft,intr,noatime,timeo=100,rsize=32768,wsize=32768  0 2
```

and my user `apoorv` can see the mounted share fine, but the `jellyfin` web interface can only see `/mnt/media` and nothing beyond that.

I installed `Jellyfin` via the package manager. What am I missing here? Have I set some permission wrong?

BTW if I enable `R/W/X` for other in the ACL menu I can access the share fine in the web interface for `Jellyfin`, but of course I don't want to do that for obvious reasons.